# Using v-for and v-if in the same element

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

Hello i'm using vuejs and i need your help to get the best practice to do this:
langs : is an object of languages :

```
langs: {'1':'fr', '2':'en', '3':'ar'},
```

has_lang : equal to 1 for the case which i need enter a value for each lang
and equal to 0 for case which i need only enter one value for all languages

What i do now :

```
    <md-layout md-gutter>
        <md-input-container v-if="has_langs" v-for="lang in langs">
            <label>@{{ attribute.attribute }} @{{ lang }}</label>
            <md-input v-model="attValues"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-input-container v-if="has_langs == 0">
            <label>@{{ attribute.attribute }} @{{ lang }}</label>
            <md-input v-model="inputa"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
    </md-layout>
```

What i need is not duplicate the input * two times
this input * :

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>@{{ attribute.attribute }} @{{ lang }}</label>
    <md-input v-model="inputa"></md-input>
</md-input-container>
```

There is a way to set v-for and v-if in the same element or something else that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can move all checks for has_langs and langs to code.

```
computed: {
   __langs(){
      return this.has_langs === 1? this.langs : {'0': 'Params for all'};
    }
},
methods: {
   manipulateWithLangs(){
    if (this.has_langs === 1){
    //do
    } else {
    // do something else
    }
  }
}



<md-layout md-gutter>
     <md-input-container v-for="lang in __langs">
        <label>@{{ attribute.attribute }} @{{ lang }}</label>
        <md-input v-model="attValues"></md-input>
    </md-input-container>
</md-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use v-if and v-for on the same element. Best to put the v-if on a parent element.

Comment: Well, you can. But it's not recommended. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for

Comment: is this still the case with vue3?

Comment: Yes, still the case with Vue3.  See: https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-essential.html#avoid-v-if-with-v-for

Answer (score 0):

You could do the `v-if` with a `v-else` on the `md-layout` the component level and get the result you want.

```
<md-layout v-if="has_langs" md-gutter>
    <md-input-container v-for="lang in langs">
        ...
    </md-input-container>
</md-layout>

<md-layout v-else md-gutter>
    <md-input-container>
        ...
    </md-input-container>
</md-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the option to create an additional filtered computed (effectively eliminating the need to use v-for and v-if on the same element), you also have a template level way of dealing with such edge-cases: the  tag.

The  tag allows you to use arbitrary template logic without actually rendering an extra element. Just remember that, because it doesn't render any element, you have to place the keys from the v-for on the actual elements, like this:

```
<template v-for="(guide, index) in guides"> <article v-if="isGuideVisible(guide)"
       :key="index"
       class="post-item post-guide"
       :class="[guide.categories.toString().replace(/,/g, ' ')]"><header>
  <h1 v-text="guide.title.rendered" /></header>
```