# how can i use variable declared inline in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm working with Vue.js (version 3) and I wanted to do something like this:

```
<div v-for="item in list" v-if="item.someAttribute === someOtherVariable">
```

but Vue returns the error:

```
Property "item" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance
```

Since, as I suppose, he's looking for *item* in *data*, where I created the Vue app.
Is there anyway to solve this issue? Maybe some workaround to obtain the same effect?

Comment: maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322217/using-v-for-and-v-if-in-the-same-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's not recommended to use `v-if` and `v-for` on the same element due to implicit precedence.

according to the [official docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-v-if)

so you should do :

```html
<template v-for="item in list">
  <div v-if="item">
    ....
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not access v-for and v-if in the same line, if you do so Priority has been given to your `v-if` condition , this was the reason you are getting that error

```
<div v-for="item in list">
  <span v-if="item.someAttribute === someOtherVariable">...</span>
</div>
```